# Carrierwave fog Amazon S3 images not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I have installed carrierwave and fog, have successfully uploaded the images and viewed them the first time, but now it does not show the images anymore.

**Here is my config file** app/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',                                       # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'AKIAJKOHTE4WTXCCXAMA',                      # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'some secret key here',                      # required
    :region                 => 'eu-east-1',                                 # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
    :host                   => 'https://s3.amazonaws.com',                  # optional, defaults to nil
    :endpoint               => 'https://s3.amazonaws.com:8080'              # optional, defaults to nil
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'createmysite.co.za'                    # required
  config.fog_public     = false                                   # optional, defaults to true
  #config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'} # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

**This is what the url looks like of the image that is supposed to display**

```
<img alt="Normal_selection_003" src="https://createmysite.co.za.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/portfolio/image/3/normal_Selection_003.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJKOHTE4WTXCCXAMA&amp;Signature=8PLq8WCkfrkthmfVGfXX9K6s5fc%3D&amp;Expires=1354859553">
```

**when I open the image url this is the output from amazon**
https://createmysite.co.za.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/portfolio/image/3/normal_Selection_003.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJKOHTE4WTXCCXAMA&Signature=8PLq8WCkfrkthmfVGfXX9K6s5fc%3D&Expires=1354859553

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>3F179B7CE417BC12</RequestId>
<HostId>
zgh46a+G7UDdpIHEEIT0C/rmijShOKAzhPSbLpEeVgUre1iDc9f7TSOwaJdQpR65
</HostId>
</Error>
```

### Update

new config file (added fog url expiry) *app/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb*

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',                                       # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'AKIAJKOHTE4WTXCCXAMA',                      # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'chuck norris',  # required
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'createmysite.co.za'                              # required
  config.fog_public     = false                                             # optional, defaults to true
  config.fog_authenticated_url_expiration = 600                             # (in seconds) => 10 minutes
end
```

works like a charm!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You've set `config.fog_public` to `false` and are using Amazon S3 for storage. URLs for private files through S3 are temporary (they're signed and have an expiry). Specifically, the URL posted in your question has an `Expires=1354859553` parameter.

`1354859553` is `Fri, 07 Dec 2012 05:52:33 GMT`, which is in the past from the current time, so the link has effectively expired, which is why you're getting the `Access Denied` error.

You can adjust the expiry out further (the default is `600` seconds) by setting

```
config.fog_authenticated_url_expiration = ... # some integer here
```

If you want non-expiring links either

- set `config.fog_public` to `true`
- have your application act as a middle man, serving the files up through `send_file`. **[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089933/showing-images-with-carrierwave-in-rails-3-1-in-a-private-store-folder)** is at least one question on SO covering this

Comment: hi, this sounds correct! I must have something buggering it up lol!, Ill post update

Comment: haha, my dev and production have diffirent db's so images where not showing on local, pulled prod db and now it seems to work pretty nicely. TX!

Comment: If I change fog_public from false to true when I have images uploaded and live on my app, how do I get the images working correctly?  Reprocess them?

Comment: You need to change the ACL on those objects to allow 'everyone' view permissions. One way is to write a small script *(or even a rake task through your Rails app)* to iterate the objects in the bucket, marking each to be public. Check out **[`acl=`](https://github.com/fog/fog/blob/master/lib/fog/aws/models/storage/file.rb#L33)** in the **[fog](https://github.com/fog/fog)** gem. You would just set this to `"public-read"` for each file and call `save`. There may be a simpler way directly through the AWS panel, but you can see how simple it is with this gem.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me with the same general issue

Comment: @deefour can you please tell me the maximum expiry time of fog_authenticated_url_expiration