# Increase the default timeout for MiniMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, minimagick

We're using MiniMagick to upload images to S3 on our site. Not often, but sometimes if the image is very large, I get a timeout error. I looked into alternatives for uploading, like [carrierwave direct](https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct), but we've decided not to use it yet.

How would I increase the default timeout for uploading with MiniMagick?

Comment: You're currently using carrierwave, right?

Comment: I think the problem is not from MiniMagick. You should change your timeout config in your app server or s3 itself

Comment: @jesse, yes we're using carrierwave, thanks

Comment: @Alter, I'm figuring out how to change the settings now.. Thanks

Comment: I've added this solution from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757671/carrierwave-fog-amazon-s3-images-not-displaying. So Alter, you were right, it wasn't MiniMagick, Jesse thanks for pointing me to Carrierwave. All is working so far, lets hope it doesnt come up again...