# How to display image from private folder inside View?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sendfile

I need a quick tip on something which seems really simple. I have some pictures inside private folder and would like to display them inside my View.

The only solution I found was this:

```
def show
    send_file 'some/image/url', :disposition => 'inline', :type => 'image/jpg', :x_sendfile => true
end
```

I've read that `:disposition => 'inline'` should not trigger image download and allow me to display it inside my View. The problem is that each time I trigger `show` action, image download is automatically activated and it is automatically downloaded. View for `show` action is not displayed.

How can I display that image inside my View? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I do it, and I'm not saying it's perfectly by the book, is I make a root for images and an action in the controller to render it.

So, for instance, in routes.rb

```
match '/images/:image', to: "your_controller#showpic", via: "get", as: :renderpic
```

In your controller:

```
def showpic
    send_file "some/path/#{params[:image]}.jpg", :disposition => 'inline', 
              :type => 'image/jpg', :x_sendfile => true # .jpg will pass as format
end

def show
end
```

And in your view

```
<img src="<%= renderpic_path(your image) %>">
```

Here is a working example, with fewer parameters on "send_file"

```
def showpic
    photopath = "images/users/#{params[:image]}.jpg"
    send_file "#{photopath}", :disposition => 'inline'
end
```

Comment: I have a problem with this approach that `send_file "some/path/#{params[:image]}.jpg", :disposition => 'inline', 
              :type => 'image/jpg', :x_sendfile => true` doesn't go through. Ma image source is always set on `/images/:image` and not on my path I specified for `send_file`. So it is set on url of `show.html.erb` View.

Comment: I will add a working example for you to work on. See my edit.

Comment: You should call renderpic_path("filename.jpg") or "/images/filename.jpg" for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is `type`. From documentation:

```
:type - specifies an HTTP content type
```

So the proper HTTP content type should be `image/jpeg` instead of `image/jpg`, as you can [see here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_types.rb). Try with:

`:type => 'image/jpeg'`

You also can list all available types coding `Mime::EXTENSION_LOOKUP` into a rails console.

Example:

**Controller**

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  def show_image
    image_path = File.join(Rails.root, params[:path]) # or similar
    send_file image_path, disposition: 'inline', type: 'image/jpeg', x_sendfile: true
  end
end
```

**Routes**

```
get '/image/:path', to: 'images#show_image', as: :image
```

**Views**

```
image_tag image_path('path_to_image')
```

Comment: Thank you. You are correct. Type was one of the problems. The problem with this approach is that if I put this `image_tag(path_to_show_action)`, image is now displayed inside `show` View. It is displayed in a new empty View. So, only image is displayed and I need that image to be displayed in my `show.html.erb` View with some other data.

Comment: Add a different action in your controller (route as well) with the `send_file` line and then you can use `image_tag(path_to_this_new_action)`. So you'll be able to add the image in other views.

Comment: I've added different action but for some reason `send_file` doesn't go through. When I check page source as image source there is always `/images/id_number` and that is the url of `show.html.erb` for Image model.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have the view use an image_tag to display on the view.

Similar question was raised here: [Showing images with carrierwave in rails 3.1 in a private store folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089933/showing-images-with-carrierwave-in-rails-3-1-in-a-private-store-folder)